# Do the verbs "come down to" and "amount to" have equivalent meanings?

Tags: word-usage

The sentence "*When it comes down to it, it is not worth the money*" has the same meaning as "*What amounts to it, it is too expensive*" ?

Answer (score 1):

You second example sentence,
 "What amounts to it, it is too expensive",
  is not a valid sentence. If you want to use "amounts to" in that context, you could say:
"What it amounts to, is that it's too expensive."
It's not a very graceful expression, though. A simpler way of saying the same thing is
"After consideration, it's too expensive." or just "All told, it's too expensive."